# saving from looping form with ajax codeigniter

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, codeigniter, loops

i'd like to saving form but the form are looped by array ajax

This is my ajax :

```
function Show_data(){
        $.ajax({
            type  : 'ajax',
            url   : '<?php echo base_url()?>admin-spot/warranty/FieldTable',
            async : false,
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data){

                var html = '';
                var html2 = '';
                var i;
                var link = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
                for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                    html += '<li>'+
                            '<a data-toggle="tab" href="#faq-tab-'+data[i].manufacturing_name+'" id="warranty-'+data[i].manufacturing_name+'"><img class="img-responsive" src="'+link+'/upload/manufacturing/'+data[i].logo+'" style="height: 30px; width: auto; "></a>'+
                            '</li>';
                    html2 +='<div id="faq-tab-'+data[i].manufacturing_name+'" class="tab-pane fade">'+
                            '<form href="#" id="form">'+
                            '<input type="text" name="id_warranty-'+data[i].id_warranty+'" value="'+data[i].id_warranty+'"/>'+
                            '<textarea class="ckeditor" id="ckeditor" name="description_warranty" rows="3" placeholder="Enter text . . . " >i am big boss</textarea>'+
                            '<button data-toggle="tab" id="btnSaving" onclick="Update('+data[i].id_warranty+')" class="btn btn-lg btn-success"><i class="White ace-icon fa fa-save bigger-130"></i>Save</button>'+
                            '<div align="right" class="space-8"></div>'+
                            '</div>';
                }
                $('#myTab').html(html);
                $('#contentTab').html(html2);
            }
        });
    }
```

for main problem is on the :

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" id="ckeditor" name="description_warranty" rows="3" placeholder="Enter text . . . " >i am big boss</textarea>
```

saving function already success but the text area are cannot change. its always saving what i write in code ajax although when i running the program i was edit the text area its always saving "i am big boss". example : when i running i was edit "i am big boss" to be "What The Hell". its always saved "i am big boss" and i edit in ajax :

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" id="ckeditor" name="description_warranty" rows="3" placeholder="Enter text . . . " >Yess boss</textarea>
```

when i running i was edit "Yess Boss" to be "What The Hell". its always saved "Yess boss" and i edit in ajax :

any  solution ?

Comment: It seems you have not given textarea value to saving function. Then how it know which is new value?

Comment: so how can i set a new value ?

Comment: so how can i set a new value ?, please let me know with the code

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass text area value to update() function by form action and submit button. please give unique id to fields

```
 for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                html += '<li>'+
                        '<a data-toggle="tab" href="#faq-tab-'+data[i].manufacturing_name+'" id="warranty-'+data[i].manufacturing_name+'"><img class="img-responsive" src="'+link+'/upload/manufacturing/'+data[i].logo+'" style="height: 30px; width: auto; "></a>'+
                        '</li>';
                html2 +='<div id="faq-tab-'+data[i].manufacturing_name+'" class="tab-pane fade">'+
                        '<form action="'+url+'/Update/'+data[i].id_warranty+'" id="form'+i+'">'+
                        '<input type="text" name="id_warranty-'+data[i].id_warranty+'" value="'+data[i].id_warranty+'"/>'+
                        '<textarea class="ckeditor" id="ckeditor'+i+'" name="description_warranty" rows="3" placeholder="Enter text . . . " >i am big boss</textarea>'+
                        '<button type="submit" data-toggle="tab" id="btnSaving'+i+'" class="btn btn-lg btn-success"><i class="White ace-icon fa fa-save bigger-130"></i>Save</button>'+
                        '<div align="right" class="space-8"></div>'+
                        '</div>';
            }
```

Now You can get text area value in `$this->input->post(description_warranty)` in update function and update it.

Comment: the value success to change but the url always http://[::1]/sys-web/admin-spot/warranty?id_warranty=1&description_warranty=%3Cp%3Esxasxasxsxwsqwsqws%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A

Comment: But in codeigniter best practise is to create function in controller so that you can easily call model for query.